# Sphinx: "No module named"

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I'm trying to build a documentation for my Python/Flask application using Sphinx, however I'm not able importing the file.

I import `views.py` file on `views.rst`, but an error message appears: `No module named 'catalog'`.

Inside `catalog` folder has one `__init__.py` file, however anyway the error does not change.

Would anyone know what is going on?

Thank you in advance.

**views.rst**

```
.. automodule:: catalog.views
   :members:
```

**conf.py**

```
sys_path.insert(0, os_path.abspath('../catalog'))
```

`executive` is the root folder and the files are:

```
.
├── build
├── catalog
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── views.py
├── source
│   ├── conf.py
│   ├── index.rst
│   └── views.rst
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some minutes later of asking this question, I've found the solution.

The problem was that I was passing the wrong path to sys path.

In order to Sphinx "see" my `catalog` module, I've needed to point to the root folder and not the `catalog` module.

So, I've changed the `conf.py` file to:

```
sys_path.insert(0, os_path.abspath('..'))
```

And it started to work fine.

Comment: Make sure you then do an import catalog after your sys path adjustment

Comment: There is no need to add `import catalog` in conf.py. Sphinx only needs  to be told where to look for modules.

Comment: I don't understand why the need for this path manipulation if my standard python can find the modules just fine.